# Как снять выделение у ListView?

Tags: java, graphics

нужно разработать класс, который заносит данные(числа) и рисует столбчатые диаграммы. У меня возникла проблема, которую я не могу исправить. При добавлении данных в список, метод add() срабатывает один раз и больше не запускается как бы я того не хотел. Не знаете как можно это исправить ?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.event.AncestorListener;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;

public class BarChart {


   private static JFrame frame;
    private static JList list;
    private static JPanel panel1;

    private static GraphicsComponent gc;
    private static String methodName;

    private static ArrayList<Integer> lst = new ArrayList<>();

    private static final String[] FUNC = {
            "Add",
            "Draw"
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(600, 400);
        frame.setTitle("Application");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        panel1 = new JPanel();
        panel1.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));

        list = new JList(FUNC);
        list.setLayoutOrientation(JList.VERTICAL_WRAP);

        list.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                methodName = list.getSelectedValue().toString();
                frame.setTitle(methodName);
                switch (methodName){
                    case "Add":
                        try {
                            add();
                        } catch (IOException e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        break;

                    case "Draw":
                        gc = new GraphicsComponent();
                        updateScreen();
                        break;
                }
            }
        });

        panel1.add(list);
        frame.add(panel1);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
    private static void draw(Graphics2D g2){
        Rectangle rect = null;
        Color col = null;
        int x = 40;
        int y  = Collections.max(lst);
        int temp = y;

        for (int i = 0; i < lst.size(); i++) {
            if (i > 0){
                if (lst.get(i) < 0){
                    col = Color.RED;
                    lst.set(i, lst.get(i) * (-1));
                    if (lst.get(i) > lst.get(i-1)){
                        y -= Math.abs((lst.get(i) - y)) + (lst.get(i) - lst.get(i-1))+ Collections.min(lst);
                    }
                    else{
                        y += Math.abs((lst.get(i) - y)) + ((lst.get(i-1) - lst.get(i)) - (Math.abs(temp - lst.get(i)))) + Collections.min(lst);
                    }
                }
                else{
                    col = Color.BLACK;
                    if (lst.get(i) > lst.get(i-1)){
                        y -= Math.abs((lst.get(i) - y)) + (lst.get(i) - lst.get(i-1));
                    }
                    else{
                        y += Math.abs((lst.get(i) - y)) + ((lst.get(i-1) - lst.get(i)) - (Math.abs(temp - lst.get(i))));
                    }
                }

            }

            rect = new Rectangle(x, y, 40, lst.get(i));
            x += 80;

            g2.setColor(col);
            g2.fill(rect);
            g2.draw(rect);
        }


    }

    static class GraphicsComponent extends JComponent{
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            draw(g2);
        }
    }

    private static void add() throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter number: ");

        lst.add(Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine()));
    }

    private static void updateScreen(){
        panel1.removeAll();
        //panel1.add(list);
        panel1.add(gc);
        frame.revalidate();
    }
```

}